Are these equivalent characterizations of a first order ordinary differential equation?
The usual expression that I've seen to characterize a first order linear differential equation is something like:
$y' + py + q = 0$
where $p$ and $q$ are continuous (or maybe differentiable) functions of the independent
variable (say $t$).
I've also seen definitions of arbitrary order linear differential equations that reduce to the following form in the first order case:
$ay' + by + c = 0$
Clearly, the first form is captured by the second form. Also, if $a = a(t)$ never vanishes, then dividing the second expression by $a$ transforms it into an equivalent* differential equation of the first form.

By "equivalent differential equations" I mean differential equations that have all the same solutions.

Now suppose that $a$ has some zeros. Leaving aside the trivial case where $a$ is identically zero, trouble can still arise:
Let $a$ be a differentiable function which is not identically zero but which vanishes off of the unit interval. For example,
$$a(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{}1 + \sin(2 \pi t - \pi/2)&\text{ if}\,\,\,t \in (0,1)\\0&\,\,otherwise\end{array}\right.$$
The solutions to the equation
$ay' = 0$
include all the functions that are constant on the unit interval. Among those solutions are several (I mean, lots) of non differentiable functions. Solutions of any equation of the first form are necessarily differentiable.
Even if we restrict our attention to differentiable solutions, the solutions of this latter equation are less constrained than solutions of equations of the first form. The derivatives of solutions of equations of the first form must all be continuous (or maybe differentiable). Solutions of the example above (of the second form) are entirely unconstrained off of the unit interval.
I propose that exactly one of the following is true:

I'm being too pedantic. Implicitly assumed in the (second) definition of a first order linear differential equation is that the function $a$ never vanishes.
The two definitions of a first order linear differential equation that I alluded to are not the same.
I'm misunderstanding something. (most likely option)

Please set me straight.

I've thought about it more and I feel that all three options are partially true. It seems that there is not a commonly agreed upon precise definition of a differential equation (even a first order differential equation). Still, for a first order linear differential equation, I think that most would agree that the following one is appropriate:
A first order linear differential equation is an open interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and an expression $y' = py + q$ where $p$ and $q$ are functions defined on $I$. A solution to such an equation is a differentiable function $y$ with domain $I$ satisfying the expression.
For example, according to this definition,
$I = (-\infty, 0)$, $y'(t) = 1/t$
and
$I = (0,\infty)$, $y'(t) = 1/t$
are distinct first order linear differential equations.
Similarly, a second order linear differential equation is an open connected set $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and an expression $y'' = py' + qy + r$ where $p,q,r$ are functions defined on $I$. A solution is a twice differentiable function $y$ with domain $I$ and satisfying the expression.
The generalization of this definition to an $n^{th}$ order linear differential equation is apparent, but an analogous definition of an arbitrary first order differential equation eludes me. Can anyone come up with a good one?
Thanks

Have you ever consulted the usual suspect? It defines the ODE of any order. That  ODE is linear when $F$ is linear in $y$ and its derivatives.

The WP link I gave defines the ODE of any order and that includes linear ODEs. I don't get why any analogous definition "eludes you".

Wikipedia, and scores of other sources, define a first order differential equation as an expression of the form
$F(y', y, t) = 0$ (an implicit differential equation) or $y' = f(y,t)$ (an explicit differential equation) where $F$ and $f$ are (arbitrary) functions. Leave aside the question of domain by assuming that all functions are defined on the entire real line. I still have a problem with $F$ or even $f$ being entirely unconstrained. Are you comfortable with the following "differential equations':
i) y' = y(y(t))
ii) y'(t) = y(t-1)
(saw those in another post)

I am not comfortable with those "differential equations". An ODE is something of the form $F(y',y,t)=0$ and to which we can apply the theorem of Picard & Lindelöf. That other stuff needs special treatment and I don't find that very interesting and important. Except perhaps $y'(t)=y(t-1)$ which I think is a delayed differential equation that has some applications.

I think that it would be to restrictive to enforce uniqueness/existence on the very definition of an ODE. Even in the case of first order linear equations, that condition requires that the coefficient functions $p,q$ be continuous. That would preclude consideration of equations where $q$ is a step function. I think that such equations are commonly considered.

I did not say that every ODE has to have a unique solution but what I said was that the equation relating $y,t$ and the derivatives has to be of a certain form. If you want to consider other stuff such as $y'=y(y(t))$ you should respect the established nomenclature. Besides: far more important than asking if that is an "ODE" is it to prove some theorems first.
